# Annotation equivalent for initializing a list of beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a property initialized inside a bean defined in *context.xml* like below:

```
        <property name="filters">
           <list>
            <!-- declared using annotations  -->
                <ref bean="filter1"/>
                <ref bean="filer2"/>

            </list>
        </property>
```

Is there any annotation equivalent for this, so I don't require writing a separated method with @PostConstruct and @Autowire filters one by one?

Currently, I did something like below:

```
@Component
public class Myclass{

  @Autowired 
  private Filter filter1;

  @Autowired
  private Filter filter2;


  private List<Filter> filters;

  @PostConstruct
  private void setFilters(){
    filters = List.of(filter1, filter2);
  }



}
```

Comment: @Autowired private List<Filter> filters should give you list of beans of type Filter

Comment: Read through under the section : [Using @Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. Works as expected.